# How is not lossless join decomposition verified and illustrated?

Tags: join, relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, natural-join

I'm reading about lossless join decomposition and working on the following example:
R(ABCDE) decomposed into R1(ABC), R2(BCD), R3(ACE).
The functional dependencies are A->D, D->E, B->D.

When I apply the "tableau" method I find the decomposition to be a *non lossless join*. Is there any way to use the tableau for getting an example that shows how you get spurious tuples when joining back the relations of the decomposition?

Comment: What does "the FDs are" mean? That those are all the FDs that hold? Not possible. That those are all the non-trivial FDs that hold? Not possible. That those are some of the FDs that hold? Then the question can't be answered. Find out what a cover is & why the question is not answerable unless you give a *cover* for the FDs that hold.

Comment: @DrimadesBoy, if the three FDs are a cover of the dependencies of R, then the decomposition *is* lossless.

Comment: @philipxy I'm puzzled by your "not possible". Why couldn't it be that those are a cover for the FDs that hold? OK no FD mentions `C`. That means `{C}` could be losslessly partitioned from `R`. So schema `R` is not 3NF. But that wasn't the question.

Comment: @AntC If "the FDs are" doesn't mean "a cover is" then the question is unanwerable. So what if a *different* question is answerable? PS "Partitioned from" is unclear but I will guess. Your reasoning ("That means") is not clear enough to counter. But If the 3 FDs form a cover then {C} is not necessarily a component of a non-trivial JD.

Comment: @Renzo I was referring specifically to the 'tableau' method described in the two textbooks for databases (Ullman et al, Navathe et al). Once we check the decomposition is not lossless, how to show an example of joining relations and get 'spurious' tuples?

Comment: @DrimadesBoy, if you apply correctly the tableau (the chase method, as it is called) you will find that the decomposition is lossless... For this reason you cannot find an example of join with spurious tuples.